# Javascript Optimal way of checking false statement except zero

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement

In javascript we use shortand notation `if(input){}` to check for empty or null input. We will get false for `Null, Undefined, false, 0, NAN, ""`. My requirements is that I want to get true for any number including zero so I have created a method as follows

```
function checkFalseExceptZero(value){

    if( value !== undefined && value !== null && value !== false && value !== "" && value.length !== 0 ) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

I have added all possible checks in the above method to get the desired result. I am curious if there is any quick, sweet, short or more robust approach to achieve the same?

Comment: `return !!value || value === 0`

Comment: try `typeof value === "number"` or boolean. But the three equals should not change type therefore `0 === false` yields `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple to understand answer. The **three equal signs** in JS will not convert type to check if the values equal unlike the **two equal signs**.

```
0 == false //true
0 === false //false, because 0 is a number and false is a boolean
```

Therefore, the answer, if you want to put it inside a function:

<sub>**JS:**</sub>

```
function isNumber(v) {
    return typeof v === "number"
}
```

The function will check the **type** of the variable. So it is not actually comparing the value to determine the result. The function will only return true if the type of the variable is called `number`.

<sub>**Test runs:**</sub>

```
isNumber(0) //true
isNumber(false) //false
isNumber("0") //false
isNumber(undefined) //false
```

In case you want to know, `typeof variable` will return a string.

Comment: Small caveat, might not matter for the OP, but for the sake of mentioning it: a string like '3' is not a number, but can be used for calculation. NaN returns true because it's considered a number type.

Comment: @torazaburo OP wanted "to get true for any number including zero"

Answer (score 2):

> My requirements is that I want to get true for any number including
>   zero so I have created a method as follows

```
function checkFalseExceptZero(value){
 if ( variable.constructor === Array) return !!value.length;
 return value === 0 || !!value;
}
```

This a shorter version of your function. This returns `true` only when value is `0` or a trully value.
So :

```
checkFalseExceptZero(null) ==>  false;
checkFalseExceptZero(undefined) ==>  false;
checkFalseExceptZero(false) ==>  false;
checkFalseExceptZero("") ==>  false;
checkFalseExceptZero(0) ==>  true;
checkFalseExceptZero([]) ==>  false;
checkFalseExcpetZero([1]) ==> true;
```

Comment: `value = []` will return true.

Comment: @torazaburo yes  I thought so. but in the original there is `&& value.length !== 0`

Comment: The scope might be a little unclear. @GiuseppePes made a good spot on length check the OP used. Based on the requirement the OP posted, it appears that he likely wants to return true for only numbers including zero. Does it make sense to say "otherwise, return false"?

Answer (score 1):

For any valid number, including 0, JavaScript already exposes the [isFinite](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) function. This returns false for all non-numbers, as well as for infinite and NaN

Examples (excerpt from the linked mdn page):

```
isFinite(Infinity);  // false
isFinite(NaN);       // false
isFinite(-Infinity); // false

isFinite(0);         // true
isFinite(2e64);      // true


isFinite("0");       // true, would've been false with the 
                     // more robust Number.isFinite("0")
```

Comment: `isFinite(null); // true` :(